Render deployment Error There’s an error above. Please fix it to continue
I have an error while deploying my backend nodeJs code to Render when I click on deploy its giving me an error called: There’s an error above. Please fix it to continue.
screen shot of render is as follows:

and my package.json file is as follows:
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
{
  "name": "ecommerce-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.4.1",
    "@types/validator": "^13.12.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "faker": "^6.6.6",
    "mongoose": "^8.5.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "stripe": "^16.8.0",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.9",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^22.2.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  }
}

<!-- end snippet -->

What is error? add error in question?
